# FacebookSDK folder missing in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, macos, facebook-android-sdk

OK so I'm new to Mac and have been trying to set up Eclipse. I have it installed with the Android SDK fine.

Trying to install the Facebook SDK by following the [dev site instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/). When I try to import the SDK I'm presented with no error messages but it still insists on there being errors and won't run any sample apps.

I have noticed that the step which asks you to select the appropriate files there is at the top of the list a folder called FacebookSDK.

I assume this to be the library for the sample apps but it doesnt seem to be in any version i download (currently on 3.5.2).

I also notice that under properties in the android section under library it has a big red cross (would put a picture but not sure how to get a screenshot on the mac yet)

I've looked around but had no joy any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so, after a lot of searching around I found a copy of the FacebookSDK folder that seems to be missing.

I simply added this into the directory with the samples, deleted the existing ones in Eclipse and imported them all back in as per the Facebook dev site suggests.

Once I had done this I just right clicked on each sample > properties > in the Android tab (under the library section) clicked add and selected the FacebookSDK folder.